# c# Writing an extension method to extend functionality in System.Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

I have only used extension methods a few times in the past so excuses me if this is a really stupid question.

I have a 3 different arrays of strings, I also have 3 strings that I want to search for within these arrays.

So far I have something like this:

```
if (list1.Any(x => x == term1) && list2.Any(x => x == term2) && list3.Any(x => x == term3))
            {
                //do something
            }
```

So if all terms are found the if statement should = true.

The problem I'm trying to solve with a extention method is....

There is a possibility term1, term2, term3 could have a value of "-1" if this is the case I want to ignore it in the if statement.

*So my question is, can this be done with an extension method? So instead of using list.Any() I can use list.MyMethod() that will return true if the value of any of the terms is -1.*

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your ultimate question. Could you maybe give code/pseudo code of what you're trying to accomplish (without using an extension method)?

Comment: Why not `if ((term1 == "-1" || term2 == "-1" || term3 == "-1") || (list1.Any(...) && list2.Any(...) && list3.Any(...)))`?

Comment: I don't think this makes sense as an extension method. What would it extend? Your logic requires 3 lists and 3 strings..

Comment: What Tim said...  And, what do you mean by 'ignore it in the if statement'?

Comment: I WANT to use an extension method, I didn't want to have loads of if statments

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, that would work, but I'm just trying to use this opportunity to use an extension method if its possible as I haven't had much practice..and I think it will look cleaner

Comment: When I say ignore it in the if statement I mean pretend its not there, so return true.

Comment: You shouldn't be looking for an *excuse* to use extension methods where there's no good fit. I don't see any reason to use an extension method here. It's not clear why you would have "loads of if statements" here.

Comment: Even to make it slightly more readable? Do you want to show me any way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you *can* use an extension method. Whether you *should* is a different question entirely.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool MyMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, T term)
    {
        if(term != null && term.ToString() == "-1")
          return false; // or true, whichever is your requirement.
        return list.Any(x => x == term);
    }
}
```

usage

```
if(list1.MyMethod(term1) && list2.MyMethod(term2) && list3.MyMethod(term3)) { ... }
```

nb. Don't call it `MyMethod` whatever you do!

Comment: Thanks :-) no it won't be called my method... that was just for asking the question, do you know if there any performance implications of using an extension method here, as opposed to just putting all of this in the if statement?

Comment: The overhead of calling another method. other than that, there's no difference. If you're down to optimizing method calls, I assume every other part of your code is perfecto. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could define a fairly simple method to do this. I'll assume strings, but making this use generics is not too much harder (just gets into weird logic with figuring out what -1 is generically):

```
static class MyExtensions 
{
     public static bool AnyOrMinusOne(this IEnumerable<string> list, string term) 
     {
        return term == "-1" || list.Any(x => x == term);
     }
}
```

Then your statement becomes:

```
if (list1.AnyOrMinusOne(term1) && list2.AnyOrMinusOne(term2) && list3.AnyOrMinusOne(term3))
{
    //do something
}
```